# Buildroot error when building with Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: linux-kernel, riscv, buildroot, busybox

I am trying to compile linux for RISCV Arch using buildroot(busybox). I was using 18.04 and 20.04 previously and had no issues compiling it. Right now, I have upgraded it to 21.10 for building some other stuffs. I have moved my toolchain and I can find it using the *which* command. When I try to compile linux I get some error which I havn't faced in the earlier versions.

```
>>> host-m4 1.4.18 Building

In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:328,
                 from ./signal.h:52,
                 from c-stack.c:49:
c-stack.c:55:26: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   55 | #elif HAVE_LIBSIGSEGV && SIGSTKSZ < 16384
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
  CC       closein.o
c-stack.c:134:8: error: variably modified 'buffer' at file scope
  134 |   char buffer[SIGSTKSZ];
      |        ^~~~~~
  CC       closeout.o
```

I am confused on how different versions can cause this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing similar error when trying to build for Raspberry Pi 4 64 bit using Yocto v2.7 (warrior) on Ubuntu 21.10. Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have hit a change in GNU C Library version 2.34 that can make `SIGSTKSZ` non-constant.

From the [GNU C Library 2.34 release announcement](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/2021-August/129718.html):

> - Add `_SC_MINSIGSTKSZ` and `_SC_SIGSTKSZ`.  When `_DYNAMIC_STACK_SIZE_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE` are defined, `MINSIGSTKSZ` and `SIGSTKSZ` are no longer constant on Linux.  `MINSIGSTKSZ` is redefined to `sysconf(_SC_MINSIGSTKSZ)` and `SIGSTKSZ` is redefined to `sysconf (_SC_SIGSTKSZ)`.  This supports dynamic sized register sets for modern architectural features like Arm SVE.

A possible workaround is to configure buildroot to build host-m4 version 1.4.19 instead of 1.4.18, because it no longer uses `SIGSTKSZ`.

Answer (score 3):

I saw that error when building on Ubuntu 22.04 for an embedded Linux board using Buildroot. It got stuck when building the `host-m4` package. [@Ian Abbott is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722830/4561887):

> A possible workaround is to configure buildroot to build host-m4 version 1.4.19 instead of 1.4.18, because it no longer uses `SIGSTKSZ`.

In Buildroot, to update from `m4` v 1.4.18 to 1.4.19, simply grab the latest files here: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/master/package/m4

As of right now (9 Jan. 2023), the upstream Buildroot m4 version there is
1.4.19, as shown here: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/package/m4/m4.mk#L7:

```bash
################################################################################
#
# m4
#
################################################################################

M4_VERSION = 1.4.19
M4_SOURCE = m4-$(M4_VERSION).tar.xz
M4_SITE = $(BR2_GNU_MIRROR)/m4
M4_LICENSE = GPL-3.0+
M4_LICENSE_FILES = COPYING

$(eval $(host-autotools-package))
```

### How to upgrade/update any buildroot package to the latest upstream version, from the command-line

Here is an example of how to upgrade any buildroot package from the command-line. In these commands, I am upgrading the `m4` package, to solve the problem in the OP's question. Change the word `m4` in all 3 places to the name of the package you'd like to update:

```bash
# initially:
cd path/to/buildroot
git remote add upstream https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot.git
git fetch upstream master

# then (from within the "buildroot" repo or subrepo)
rm -r package/m4
git checkout upstream/master -- package/m4
git add -A
git status
git commit -m "Update m4 library"
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/issues/9055 if you cannot upgrade to 1.4.19. You can apply patch 04 from the linked dev to fix it.